# External Shuffle service connection idle for more than 120seconds while there are outstanding requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a spark job on yarn. The job runs properly on the amazon EMR. (1 Master and 2 slave with m4.xlarge)

I have setup similar infra using HDP 2.6 distribution using aws ec2 machines. But the spark job gets stuck at one particular stage and after sometime i get the following error in container logs. The main error seems to be shuffle service being idle.

> 18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker: Doing the fetch; tracker endpoint = NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark://MapOutputTracker@10.210.150.150:44343)
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker: Don't have map outputs for shuffle 9, fetching them
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker: Don't have map outputs for shuffle 9, fetching them
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker: Got the output locations
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 5 non-empty blocks out of 1000 blocks
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 1 remote fetches in 0 ms
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 5 non-empty blocks out of 1000 blocks
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 5 non-empty blocks out of 1000 blocks
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 1 remote fetches in 0 ms
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 5 non-empty blocks out of 1000 blocks
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 1 remote fetches in 1 ms
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO codegen.CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4.822611 ms
>   18/06/25 07:15:31 INFO codegen.CodeGenerator: Code generated in 8.430244 ms
>   18/06/25 07:17:31 ERROR server.TransportChannelHandler: Connection to ip-10-210-150-180.********/10.210.150.180:7447 has been quiet for 120000 ms while there are outstanding requests. Assuming connection is dead; please adjust spark.network.timeout if this is wrong.
>   18/06/25 07:17:31 ERROR client.TransportResponseHandler: Still have 307 requests outstanding when connection from ip-10-210-150-180.********/10.210.150.180:7447 is closed
>   18/06/25 07:17:31 INFO shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Retrying fetch (1/3) for 197 outstanding blocks after 5000 ms
>   18/06/25 07:17:31 ERROR shuffle.OneForOneBlockFetcher: Failed while starting block fetches
>   java.io.IOException: Connection from ip-10-210-150-180.********/10.210.150.180:7447 closed
>   at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelInactive(TransportResponseHandler.java:146)
>   at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelInactive(TransportChannelHandler.java:108)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
>   at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
>   at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:278)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
>   at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
>   at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
>   at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelInactive(TransportFrameDecoder.java:182)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
>   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1289)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
>   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:893)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:691)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   18/06/25 07:17:31 INFO shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Retrying fetch (1/3) for 166 outstanding blocks after 5000 ms
>   18/06/25 07:17:31 ERROR shuffle.OneForOneBlockFetcher: Failed while starting block fetches
>   java.io.IOException: Connection from ip-10-210-150-180.********/10.210.150.180:7447 closed
>   at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelInactive(TransportResponseHandler.java:146)
>   at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelInactive(TransportChannelHandler.java:108)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
>   at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
>   at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:278)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
>   at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
>   at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
>   at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelInactive(TransportFrameDecoder.java:182)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
>   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1289)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
>   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:893)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:691)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I am currently running spark on yarn cluster with the following spark-defaults configurations

```
spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs:///user/spark/applicationHistory
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.yarn.historyServer.address=ppv-qa12-tenant8-spark-cluster-master.periscope-solutions.local:18080
spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
spark.driver.maxResultSize=0
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.executor.memory=5g
spark.driver.memory=1g
spark.executor.cores=4
```

And i have the following set in yarn-site.xml in nodemanager of slave machines

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
    <value>/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/aux/*,/etc/hadoop/conf,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>spark2_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark2_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.container-manager.thread-count</name>
    <value>64</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>20</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
    <value>5</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>************</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>64</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>64</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>32</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>128</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>32</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.timeline-service.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>8</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>11520</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>11520</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>*************</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Edit : Through some network debugging I found that epehmeral port created by container to connect with shuffle service is actively refusing connection. (telnet immediately throws error)

Comment: Could you please ensure whether the shuffle service is running correctly in all the workers ? Sometimes shuffle service stops silently and ends up these erros

Comment: No the shuffle service is being run in all machines. Currently it is run as an auxiliary service of yarn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On looking into kernel and system activity logs we found the following issue in `/var/log/messages`

> xen_netfront: xennet: skb rides the rocket: 19 slots

That means that our aws ec2 machines were having network packet loss.

The data transfer b/n container and shuffle service happen through RPC Calls (ChunkFetchRequest, ChunkFetchSuccess and ChunkFetchFailure) and these RPC calls were suppressed by the network.

More info on this log can be found in the following thread.

http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-09-11/perf-kernel-line-tracing.html

The log message means that we are exceeding the maximum buffer size of the packet that can be put in the driver ring buffer queue(16) and those SKB's were lost

Scatter-gather collects multiple responses and sends them as a single response which in turn is responsible for an increase in the SKB size.

So we turned off the scatter-gather using the following command.

```
sudo ethtool -K eth0 sg off
```

After this there were no more packet loss.

Performance is also similar to that we used to have in EMR.

Comment: hi, I have similar issue as well. Are you enabling auto scale in EMR as well?

Comment: @NebiMAydin, This wasn't on EMR. I was building a Spark cluster by building an AMI with spark installation and scaling them using auto scaling group.
EMR should by default have turned off scatter-gather.